# Arch Linux gets stuck on boot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub2

I followed the [Arch Linux Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners) up to the section [Unmount the partitions and reboot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners#Unmount_the_partitions_and_reboot).
After rebooting (I use grub as bootloader) without the `quiet` parameter, I get the following output:

[image: After boot]

At this point Arch is stuck. The computer is an Acer Aspire One D270.

Anybody got an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Strange, it looks like it's loaded correctly but is not giving you a prompt. Is there any difference if you switch to another tty (Alt+F2 or any other F key)? Also see [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1335072).

Comment: It's stuck. It does not respond to any kind of input not even to a press of the power button.

Comment: OK, have a look at the link I posted in my previous comment. Also, have a look at the many many google results for [arch hangs at "welcome+to+arch+linux"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=arch+hangs+at+"welcome+to+arch+linux").

Comment: It seems like it's a problem with systemd on my specific hardware. I need to downgrade my systemd to 204-3 but i can't find it as 32-bit package

Answer (score 1):

One solution that worked for me was to downgrade `systemd` to an older version, systemd 207-5.

Answer (score 0):

Though probably unlinked to OP older issue, my Atom n450 Arch hanged upon boot with any kernel >4.0.x. Untill given the solution by a nice fellow:

`systemd.restore_state=0` kernel parameter allows the latest ARCH kernels to boot my dell mini 1012. Now running great. Source here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201523&p=2