# Linux Mint 32 bit with Cinnamon won't boot after install

Tags: linux-mint

I have a Dell Mini 1012 my sister gave me. It was running Windows 10 but very slowly so I wiped it and installed Linux Mint 32 bit from the US Download Mirrors (I did it twice from a couple of the university mirrors). It installs fine, but after it installs and I reboot I get the Mint boot screen with the little dots and it runs a few times and then just hangs on the second dot and does not boot. Does anyone have any idea why? I've installed it twice from different mirrors and still get the same problem.

I should say there is a point before the installation where it asks if you want to download 3rd party drivers for the graphics, wireless card etc and I do accept those. Do you think that could be the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you hit F2 as soon as the Mint boot screen appears, does it change from an image to text output?

Comment: Nothing happens when I press F2. The boot screen stays there.

Comment: On the 'grub' screen, press 'e', to edit the params to remove 'quiet splash'
and add 'single', for debugging....

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, I'm new here so don't have rep. of 50+, needed to post as comment)

Add (via grub e[dit]) this: 
systemd.restore_state=0

[Arch Linux gets stuck on boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98091/arch-linux-gets-stuck-on-boot/293565#293565)

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/system-freezes-during-boot-up-when-using-kernel-4-1-or-later-4175559486

The issue seems to be: 4.x kernel on Atom N450 (etc), per web search string:

kernel 4* boot hang atom systemd.restore_state=0